# SQL Query Slow Execution

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Query unexpectedly taking three times as long to execute:

```
SELECT p.rowid as 'promosk_rowid',s.id_pro as 'promosId',s.*,p.*,c.*,m.*
FROM promos s
LEFT JOIN promost t ON t.pro_prs=s.id_pro
LEFT JOIN promrule m ON m.pro_prr=s.id_pro
LEFT JOIN promosk p ON p.pro_psk=s.id_pro,coupons c
WHERE c.id_cpn=s.cpn_pro
AND c.typ_cpn='1'
AND c.act_cpn <> 'N'
AND s.act_pro <> 'N'
AND p.rowid IS NULL
AND t.rowid IS NULL
AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-09-25','%Y-%m-%d') >= s.sd_pro
AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-09-25','%Y-%m-%d') <= s.ed_pro

UNION

SELECT p.rowid as 'promosk_rowid',s.id_pro as 'promosId',s.*,p.*,c.*,m.*
FROM promos s
LEFT JOIN promost t ON t.pro_prs=s.id_pro
LEFT JOIN promrule m ON m.pro_prr=s.id_pro,promosk p,articles a,coupons c
WHERE s.id_pro=p.pro_psk
AND c.typ_cpn='1'
AND c.id_cpn=s.cpn_pro
AND c.act_cpn <> 'N'
AND s.act_pro <> 'N'
AND (a.article='0030269484')
AND (p.art_psk = a.article OR p.art_psk = '')
AND (p.coll_psk = a.collect OR p.coll_psk = '')
AND (p.type_psk = a.type_c OR p.type_psk = '')
AND (p.pat_psk = a.pat_c OR p.pat_psk = '')
AND (p.scl_psk = a.sclass_c OR p.scl_psk = '')
AND (p.cl1_psk = a.cl1_c OR p.cl1_psk = '')
AND (p.cl2_psk = a.cl2_c OR p.cl2_psk = '')
AND (p.ven_psk = a.model_c OR p.ven_psk = '')
AND (p.colr_psk = a.color_c OR p.colr_psk = '')
AND (p.siz_psk = a.size1 OR p.siz_psk = '')
AND (p.styl_psk = a.venitem OR p.styl_psk = '')
AND t.rowid IS NULL
AND p.rowid IS NOT NULL
AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-09-25','%Y-%m-%d') >= s.sd_pro
AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-09-25','%Y-%m-%d') <= s.ed_pro

UNION

SELECT p.rowid as 'promosk_rowid',s.id_pro as 'promosId',s.*,p.*,c.*,m.*
FROM promos s
LEFT JOIN promost t ON t.pro_prs=s.id_pro
LEFT JOIN promrule m ON m.pro_prr=s.id_pro
LEFT JOIN promosk p ON p.pro_psk=s.id_pro,coupons c,stores r
WHERE c.id_cpn=s.cpn_pro
AND c.typ_cpn='1'
AND c.act_cpn <> 'N'
AND s.act_pro <> 'N'
AND t.rowid IS NOT NULL
AND p.rowid IS NULL
AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-09-25','%Y-%m-%d') >= s.sd_pro
AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-09-25','%Y-%m-%d') <= s.ed_pro
AND r.st_num='218657'
AND (t.stc_prs = r.st_num OR t.stc_prs = '-1')
AND (t.clnt_prs = r.st_clnt OR t.clnt_prs = '-1')

UNION

SELECT p.rowid as 'promosk_rowid',s.id_pro as 'promosId',s.*,p.*,c.*,m.*
FROM promos s
LEFT JOIN promost t ON t.pro_prs=s.id_pro
LEFT JOIN promrule m ON m.pro_prr=s.id_pro,
promosk p,
articles a,
coupons c,
stores r
WHERE s.id_pro=p.pro_psk
AND c.typ_cpn='1'
AND c.id_cpn=s.cpn_pro
AND c.act_cpn <> 'N'
AND s.act_pro <> 'N'
AND (a.article='0030269484')
AND (p.art_psk = a.article OR p.art_psk = '')
AND (p.coll_psk = a.collect OR p.coll_psk = '')
AND (p.type_psk = a.type_c OR p.type_psk = '')
AND (p.pat_psk = a.pat_c OR p.pat_psk = '')
AND (p.scl_psk = a.sclass_c OR p.scl_psk = '')
AND (p.cl1_psk = a.cl1_c OR p.cl1_psk = '')
AND (p.cl2_psk = a.cl2_c OR p.cl2_psk = '')
AND (p.ven_psk = a.model_c OR p.ven_psk = '')
AND (p.colr_psk = a.color_c OR p.colr_psk = '')
AND (p.siz_psk = a.size1 OR p.siz_psk = '')
AND (p.styl_psk = a.venitem OR p.styl_psk = '')
AND t.rowid IS NOT NULL
AND p.rowid IS NOT NULL
AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-09-25','%Y-%m-%d') >= s.sd_pro
AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-09-25','%Y-%m-%d') <= s.ed_pro
AND r.st_num='218657'
AND (t.stc_prs = r.st_num OR t.stc_prs = '-1')
AND (t.clnt_prs = r.st_clnt OR t.clnt_prs = '-1')
;
```

The execution plan is:

```
+----+--------------+----------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table          | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                      | key     | key_len | ref               | rows  | Extra                                |
+----+--------------+----------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | c              | ref    | PRIMARY,typ_cpn                                                                                                                                    | typ_cpn | 5       | const             |    52 | Using where                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | s              | ref    | cpn_pro                                                                                                                                            | cpn_pro | 13      | pandora.c.id_cpn  |     1 | Using where                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | t              | ref    | pro_prs                                                                                                                                            | pro_prs | 5       | pandora.s.id_pro  |    25 | Using where; Using index; Not exists |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | m              | ref    | pro_prr                                                                                                                                            | pro_prr | 5       | pandora.s.id_pro  |     1 |                                      |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | p              | ref    | pro_psk                                                                                                                                            | pro_psk | 5       | pandora.s.id_pro  |   781 | Using where; Not exists              |
|  2 | UNION        | a              | const  | PRIMARY,type_c,model_c,collect,color_c,pat_c,sclass_c,cl1_c,cl2_c,venitem,venitem__act,model_c__venitem__color_c,collect__venitem,model_c__venitem | PRIMARY | 12      | const             |     1 |                                      |
|  2 | UNION        | p              | ALL    | rowid,pro_psk,art_psk                                                                                                                              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL              | 34364 | Using where                          |
|  2 | UNION        | s              | eq_ref | PRIMARY,cpn_pro                                                                                                                                    | PRIMARY | 4       | pandora.p.pro_psk |     1 | Using where                          |
|  2 | UNION        | t              | ref    | pro_prs                                                                                                                                            | pro_prs | 5       | pandora.p.pro_psk |    25 | Using where; Using index; Not exists |
|  2 | UNION        | m              | ref    | pro_prr                                                                                                                                            | pro_prr | 5       | pandora.p.pro_psk |     1 |                                      |
|  2 | UNION        | c              | eq_ref | PRIMARY,typ_cpn                                                                                                                                    | PRIMARY | 12      | pandora.s.cpn_pro |     1 | Using where                          |
|  3 | UNION        | r              | const  | PRIMARY,st_clnt                                                                                                                                    | PRIMARY | 4       | const             |     1 |                                      |
|  3 | UNION        | c              | ref    | PRIMARY,typ_cpn                                                                                                                                    | typ_cpn | 5       | const             |    52 | Using where                          |
|  3 | UNION        | s              | ref    | PRIMARY,cpn_pro                                                                                                                                    | cpn_pro | 13      | pandora.c.id_cpn  |     1 | Using where                          |
|  3 | UNION        | m              | ref    | pro_prr                                                                                                                                            | pro_prr | 5       | pandora.s.id_pro  |     1 |                                      |
|  3 | UNION        | t              | ref    | rowid,pro_prs                                                                                                                                      | pro_prs | 5       | pandora.s.id_pro  |    25 | Using where                          |
|  3 | UNION        | p              | ref    | pro_psk                                                                                                                                            | pro_psk | 5       | pandora.t.pro_prs |   781 | Using where; Not exists              |
|  4 | UNION        | a              | const  | PRIMARY,type_c,model_c,collect,color_c,pat_c,sclass_c,cl1_c,cl2_c,venitem,venitem__act,model_c__venitem__color_c,collect__venitem,model_c__venitem | PRIMARY | 12      | const             |     1 |                                      |
|  4 | UNION        | r              | const  | PRIMARY,st_clnt                                                                                                                                    | PRIMARY | 4       | const             |     1 |                                      |
|  4 | UNION        | p              | ALL    | rowid,pro_psk,art_psk                                                                                                                              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL              | 34364 | Using where                          |
|  4 | UNION        | s              | eq_ref | PRIMARY,cpn_pro                                                                                                                                    | PRIMARY | 4       | pandora.p.pro_psk |     1 | Using where                          |
|  4 | UNION        | m              | ref    | pro_prr                                                                                                                                            | pro_prr | 5       | pandora.p.pro_psk |     1 |                                      |
|  4 | UNION        | t              | ref    | rowid,pro_prs                                                                                                                                      | pro_prs | 5       | pandora.p.pro_psk |    25 | Using where                          |
|  4 | UNION        | c              | eq_ref | PRIMARY,typ_cpn                                                                                                                                    | PRIMARY | 12      | pandora.s.cpn_pro |     1 | Using where                          |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2,3,4> | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL              |  NULL |                                      |
+----+--------------+----------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+
25 rows in set (0.19 sec)
```

The issue happens using InnoDB tables.
Any additional information, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you have 4 `SELECT`s that you are `UNION`ing. Start by running them separately and find out which one(s) is the slow one. The execution plan would be smaller and much simpler to read and analyze. MySQL plans are known to be hard to read in the first place and your [unnecessary] massive query is not helping.

Comment: Anything that produces a query plan that long is going to be something I'll immediately suspect of being slow. If this is a real impediment, have you considered creating a `VIEW` and materializing that for faster access times?